# finding difficult to login in gmail

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While entering only username no problem is occurred. But, if i write code to enter both username & password another page is coming.

ex.

```
obj.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("xxxxx"); //no problem required page coming and entering username.
if i write two 
ex.  obj.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
     obj.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxxxx");// different page coming unable to enter username and password.
```

Comment: Are you using the new gmail.com login?  I would also be curious what the actual error message you're seeing is.

Comment: it is unable to find password element because page is changing as i told

Comment: Here the main question will be which Gmail login are you referring, the older login page or the newly implemented login page?

Comment: Agree with Swagin9 You will want to add a wait step to wait for the password field to be visible before trying to send the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding problem with gmail is: It have 2 pages for login.

1. User Name
2. Password

So steps should be:

1. Enter user name
2. click on Next
3. Enter password.
4. Click on signin.

Sharing the sample code. Just remember google have change their page. So giving both code which work on new page as well as on old page.

```
driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
// **** checking if url is of new then use if code otherwise else code.
if(driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?")){
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("password"))); 
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
    }
    else{
        driver.findElement(By.name("Email")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("Passwd")));
        driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("xxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();
    }
```

I hope it will help you. Please ignore the multiple creation of wait object. Just provide the snippet.

Comment: . your thought is really excellent but unable to enter password in the both situations . how can i  enter ?        (i tried with wait object and without wait object unable to enter)

Comment: i mean in the if block and else block in both the situations am unable to enter password.   thanks

Comment: Few questions:
1. Are you able to move to next screen (password screen)
2. If possible share exception and your code?
3. Can you share the Google login page screenshots?

Comment: I was able to do login using above code. Freshly tried then share over here.

Comment: Are you able to login now?

Comment: yeah if block is working perfectly , but in else after entering password , sighin button not working. see the error below .. i will send you the error  in two comments   .

Comment: this is not allowing me to send u error , it is showing too many character.  ok i will solve it by myself i like your logic please try to explain me these two line in that code  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("password")));

Comment: is it mandatory to write webDriverWait class why should we wait ? isn't Thread.sleep not enough.

Comment: ERROR   SHOWING LIKE THIS                       Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds

Comment: Hi Anusha,
first line: 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
Here we are creating a webdriver wait object which wait max for 20 seconds. Its mean where ever we use wait object to identify element suing webdriver than it look for element for max 20 second. If it found in 10 sec then it will move forward and not wait for whole 20 sec.

Comment: Now second line: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.na‌​me("password")));

using wait object with condition:
Is element present which represent here as presenceOfElementLocated
So it will wait for max 20 sec for element By.name("password") to be present on screen. If not found then throw error :

element not found.
Check following links for information:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#expected-conditions

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

Comment: thank you. is there any difference between element not found and element not visible errors?

Comment: yes....
Element no found means: Element does not exists on the page at all...
Element not visible means: Element present on the page but might be hidden.. like its hidden property is true. Or its not visible on current screen like page is big and scroll is needed to reach to that element. In that case also it throw element not visible. In that case you need to scroll down first and then look for element for any action

Answer (score 1):

You will want to add a wait step to wait for the password field to be visible before trying to send the value

Comment: page is changing and unable to locate password element. read my question once again.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, which is why you need to add a wait step to wait for the page to stop changing before you try to send the password value.

Answer (score 0):

Normally something like this should do the job  :

```
driver.get(link)

# find email, send data and submit
EMAIL_FIELD = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
EMAIL_FIELD.click()
EMAIL_FIELD.clear()
EMAIL_FIELD.send_keys(Email)
EMAIL_FIELD.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('1_email_input.png')


driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='identifierNext']/content/span").submit()
time.sleep(3)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('2_input_entered.png')

# find password, send data and submit
PASSWD_FIELD = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
PASSWD_FIELD.click()
PASSWD_FIELD.clear()
PASSWD_FIELD.send_keys(Passwd)
PASSWD_FIELD.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('3_password_input.png')

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='identifierNext']/content/span").submit()
time.sleep(3)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('4_password_entered.png')

# get cookies
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

But at the moment I also can't get it working, very odd, the email is not actually posted anymore. Not like this and not with send_keys(Keys.ENTER) on the email field itself.