# How to locate any element on browser using location of the element?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I just want to click somewhere on the window. Do we have any method to locate some element or anything on web browser to click on it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Amar\\Selinium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https:\\www.google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("SIGN IN")).click();
    WebElement Email = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
    Email.sendKeys("abc@gmail@gmail.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
    Thread.sleep(60);
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("PASSWORD");
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to `click somewhere` in the window? What purpose does it serves for your automation? Please add more information and context to your question.

Comment: You can click (or sendKeys or whatever) to the body of the browser window as follows: driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).click();

Comment: @BillHileman - not sure why your answer was downvoted and converted to a comment. I think it is exactly what (as confused as he is) OP asked for.

Comment: I assume you want to click anywhere on a page outside puldown, to finalize selection?

Comment: Thanks, @PeterMasiar, I thought it was a completely valid question, but I guess a moderator did not understand or needed justification.  I know, for example, that to open a new tab, one can send a control-T to the browser body this way, and I don't know why that wouldn't work for other things.  There could indeed be a web site somewhere that performs some action when a click is performed, perhaps outside of expected area, to notify a user of some message, so I think it's legit.

Comment: Moderator please explain my downvote.

Comment: @BillHileman - downvote is likely not from moderator. Likely, moderator noticed a downvote, and considered the downvote as a signal from the community that answers is better as a comment (which I disagree, common mantra is **"do not answer in comments"** ) Anonymous drive-by downvotes are just a fact of life. As my boss says: "Life is not fair - and then you die". :-)

Comment: @alexce - Can you consider explaining the conversion of the Bills' answer to a comment? If my hunch is correct and OP wanted just to click **anywhere** to close the selection, it would not be (exact) duplicate, and his answer is right on the money, I think.

Comment: @alexce I also second Peters comment

Comment: @AmarKanchi - Do you agree your question is duplicate? Did the link solved your problem? We want to help you to solve your problem, but we need more info from you. What is very frustrating when someone asks the question and then abandons it. Sometimes it seems that we (SE community) care more, and are more invested in answering the question than the person who originally asked it.

Comment: i got this problem while testing gmail sign-in. I entered email then clicked on next button I navigated to password page. But there I am unable to locate any element in that page tried with all locators. I am getting No such element exception.. so I thought of clicking somewhere in the page so that I can locate the password field.

Comment: Can this help you? https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27022/finding-difficult-to-login-in-gmail

Answer (score 1):

You just want to click on a page? I really doubt that will solve your issue but here goes:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).click();
```

It just clicks the webpage. In all my testing it has not ever clicked on a real element (as in, accidentally clicked a link), but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I can see a use case for this.  In our case, we have a framework that sometimes won't recognize an element on a page if the page is not clicked into first.  In our case, we just click on a harmless element (one that can't be selected), then click the desired element.  I'll have to try this and see if it works in our case.